# ColdFusion 11 Server Update - Updates don't download on RHEL 7

Tags: coldfusion, rhel, rhel7

The Server Update > Updates page will not let me download the updates. I can click the buttons but they don't do anything. The "Check for updates" button works.

The CF 11 servers that are running Windows Server 2012 and RHEL 5 have tabs on the page like this:

---

[image]

Whereas the RHEL 7 servers have each tab section on one page. Like this:

---

[image]

Comment: I'm not a server guy, but I would expect the Server Updates functionality to be restricted to the operating system, not the installed applications.

Comment: @DanBracuk Well this is just for the ColdFusion Server updates, not the OS updates. Anit has the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lockdwon applied on the RHEL 7 server. The reason you don't see different tabs and everything on one single page is, because AJAX functionality is blocked. You can confirm the same by checking **Default ScriptSrc Directory** under "Server Settings > Settings". By default its set to /CFIDE/scripts. If you change it back to the "default value", you will be able to see the updates. Once you have downloaded/installed the update, you can change it back to the previous value.

Or, if you don't want to toggle between the "Default ScriptSrc Directory" then, you can install the update manually. The instructions are mentioned [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/using-the-coldfusion-administrator.html#ServerUpdatesection).

Comment: Wow that was it. Thank you!